Unable to retrieve the "Assembly method" of an assembly using Edirect in the terminal
I am having a list of assembly ID and would like to retrieve specific info on the assembly method (eg. SPADes) from the docsum of that assembly. I have been trying these codes that worked for some other retrievable info, but I could not find the Assembly method although it is shown on the ncbi website. I also inspected the docsum itself where I can not find assembly method. I still see some tutorial using some commands as shown below but it did not work.
printing the docsum
esearch -db assembly -query "GCF_037000505.1" | efetch -format docsum 
I looked into this, there is no assembly method
Some tutorials suggested
efetch -db assembly -id GCF_037000505.1 -format docsum | xtract -pattern DocumentSummary -element AssemblyMethod
This did not produce any output.
Can you advise on a way in linux using esearch to retrieve the assembly method ? Why it is not retrieved via docsum although present on ncbi ?
Thanks
